# Issues wih the Wordpress API Customization

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making my very first Wordpress Theme and I'm learning the API Customization. But there's something wrong about this code I made. What's wrong? When I load the wp-admin page, it's shown blank.

This is the PHP Code

```
//Welcome Message Settings

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'welcome_message' , array(
        'default'     => 'hi',
    ));

        $wp_customize->add_section( 'test_welcomemessage' , array(
        'title'      => __('Welcome Message','my_test'),
        'description'   => 'Write your own Welcome Message for your visitors'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'welcome_message', array(
        'label'      => __( 'Welcome Messagee', 'mytheme' ),
        'section'    => 'test_welcomemessage',
        'settings'   => 'welcome_message'
    )));

}
```

And this is the HTML Structure

```
<div id="welcomecontainer"> 
<div class="welcomemessage"><?php echo get_theme_mod('welcome_message'); ?></div>
</div>
```

What's wrong in this code?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to make use of `$wp_customize->..` you need to make use of `customize_register` hook:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'register_my_settings' );
function register_my_settings( $wp_customize ){
  $wp_customize->add_section( 'test_welcomemessage' , array(
    'title'      => __('Welcome Message','my_test'),
    'description'   => 'Write your own Welcome Message for your visitors'
  ));
}
```

(I'm not sure if order is important here, but you need to have: `add_section`, `add_setting` then `add_control`)

Besides that, when developing, make sure you have `WP_DEBUG` set to true (edit `wp-config.php` in your project's root, and to the end of the file you will find this setting) in order to see all errors (also, make sure that server is set to display errors)